# Как выравнивать кнопку по центру, а относительно её уже расположить текст?

Tags: html, css

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/sp10nfou/1/):

```
<div>
  <span>текст</span>
  <button>000|000</button>
  <span>длинный текст</span>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно расположить кнопку по центру экрана, а текст уже относительно кнопки раздвинуть на 10px.
То есть кнопка должна быть всего по центру блока, не зависимо от текста.
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем на **Flex**.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item1 {
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 50px);
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.item2 {
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 50px);
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.center {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item1">текст</span>
  <button class="center">---|---</button>
  <span class="item2">длинный текст, длинный текст</span>
</div>
```

Если ширина центрального элемента заранее неизвестна то делаем на **Grid-Layout**.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.item1 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item1">текст</span>
  <button>---|---</button>
  <span>длинный текст, длинный текст</span>
</div>
```

Comment: А если центрального блока ширина заранее не известна?

Comment: @Mr_Epic добавил в ответ.